# Wordpress - fetch data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have these two different tables (wp_usermeta & my cutom  table-sia_licence):

**wp_usermeta table:-**
[image]
**sia_licence table(custom):-**
[image]
and I want final data table to be like this:-

### [image]

**We tried using**

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta, sia_licence WHERE  wp_usermeta.user_id = sia_user_id  
        AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
        AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name'
        AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'phone_number'
        AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'email'
        AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'address'");
```

but getting blank array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform conditional aggregation on `wp_usermeta` in order to pivot all attributes (first name, last name, ...) per `user_id` and then `JOIN` with `sia_licence` to produce desired output

```
SELECT q.user_id, q.first_name, q.last_name, q.email, q.phone_number, q.address,
       l.select_licence, l.visa_expiry, l.licence_number, l.sia_licence, l.driving_licence
  FROM 
(
  SELECT user_id, 
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name'   THEN meta_value END) first_name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name'    THEN meta_value END) last_name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'phone_number' THEN meta_value END) phone_number,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'email'        THEN meta_value END) email,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'address'      THEN meta_value END) address
    FROM wp_usermeta m
   WHERE EXISTS
  (
      SELECT *
        FROM sia_licence
       WHERE sia_user_id = m.user_id
  )
   GROUP BY user_id
) q JOIN sia_licence l
    ON q.user_id = l.sia_user_id
```

or join first and then aggregate

```
SELECT q.user_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name'   THEN meta_value END) first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name'    THEN meta_value END) last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'phone_number' THEN meta_value END) phone_number,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'email'        THEN meta_value END) email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'address'      THEN meta_value END) address,
       MAX(select_licence)  select_licence,
       MAX(visa_expiry)     visa_expiry,
       MAX(licence_number)  licence_number,
       MAX(sia_licence)     sia_licence,
       MAX(driving_licence) driving_licence
  FROM wp_usermeta q JOIN sia_licence l
    ON q.user_id = l.sia_user_id
 GROUP BY q.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta wu
 INNER JOIN sia_licence sl ON wu.user_id = sl.sia_user_id
 WHERE <you can specify your filter here>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does sla_user_id reference user_id?

if so you want to use a JOIN like this...

```
SELECT um.*,sl.select_licence,sl.visa_expiry,sl.licence_number,sl.sia_licence,sl.driving_licence FROM `wp_usermeta`um JOIN `sia_licence`sl ON um.`user_id`=sl.`sia_user_id`;
```

You can also add a where clause like this

```
SELECT um.*,sl.select_licence,sl.visa_expiry,sl.licence_number,sl.sia_licence,sl.driving_licence FROM `wp_usermeta`um JOIN `sia_licence`sl ON um.`user_id`=sl.`sia_user_id` WHERE um.`user_id`=101;
```

if neeeded. IN the above example it would just return user ID = 101.

You can also just use SELECT *, in this case, but generally it's a bad idea because if there are any ambigious columns (columns with the same names) between the two tables it'll give you an error, but in your case it looks like you should be fine with:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta`um JOIN `sia_licence`sl ON um.`user_id`=sl.`sia_user_id`;
```